# libgdx Textures are rendered as black rectangles

Tags: android, libgdx

I've got the following class:

```
public class Food extends AbstractActor {

private float width;
private float height;

public Food() {
    super(new Texture("food.png"));
}

@Override
public void update(float dt) {

}

public static Food fromJSON(JSONObject json) {
    Food food = new Food();

    try {
        food.setPosition((float)json.getDouble("x"), (float)json.getDouble("y"));
        food.setWidth((float)json.getDouble("width"));
        food.setHeight((float)json.getDouble("height"));
    } catch(Exception e) {}

    return food;
}

public float getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public void setWidth(float width) {
    this.width = width;
}

public float getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(float height) {
    this.height = height;
}
}
```

and an AbstractActor:

```
public abstract class AbstractActor {

private Texture texture;

private float x;
private float y;

public AbstractActor(Texture texture) {
    this.texture = texture;
}

public void setPosition(float x, float y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public float getX() {
    return x;
}

public float getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setTexture(Texture texture) {
    this.texture = texture;
}

public Texture getTexture() {
    return texture;
}

public abstract void update(float dt);

public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
    sb.begin();
    sb.draw(texture, getX(), getY());
    sb.end();
}

public void dispose() {
    getTexture().dispose();
}
}
```

the image food.png really exists and is present in the assets folder.
The problem is, that almost every texture is being rendered as black rectangle. Any Ideas how to fix this? (I am running it on android device)

**EDIT**
more code:

```
public class GdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {


public static final int WIDTH = 860;
public static final int HEIGHT = 480;

public static final String TITLE = "Fishy";

private static OrthographicCamera camera;

private GameStateManager gsm;
private SpriteBatch batch;

@Override
public void create () {
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    camera.translate(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    gsm = new GameStateManager();

    gsm.push(new MenuState(gsm));
}

@Override
public void render () {
    camera.update();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gsm.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    gsm.render(batch);
}

public static OrthographicCamera getCameraInstance() {
    return camera;
}
}
```

GameStateManager:

```
public class GameStateManager {

private Stack<State> states;

public GameStateManager() {
    states = new Stack<State>();
}

public void push(State state) {
    states.push(state);
}

public void pop() {
    states.pop();
}

public void set(State state) {

    states.pop();
    states.push(state);
}

public void update(float dt) {
    states.peek().update(dt);
}

public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
    states.peek().render(sb);
}

}
```

and the problematic PlayingState where the black rectangles are rendered:

```
public class PlayingState extends State implements OnMessageReceived, OnConnectionFailed {

private static TCPClient client;

private String message;
private BitmapFont font;

private Player me;
private World world;

private Background background;
private Foreground foreground;


public PlayingState(GameStateManager gsm, String name, String type) {
    super(gsm);

    background = new Background();
    foreground = new Foreground();

    client = new TCPClient(this, this);
    client.start();


    font = new BitmapFont();
    font.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("type", type);
        json.put("name", name);
        client.sendMessage(MessageType.INIT, json);
    } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}

@Override
public void handleInput() {
}

@Override
public void update(float dt) {
    handleInput();

    if(world != null && me != null) {
        Player player = world.getPlayerById(me.getId());
        if(player != null)
            me = player;
    }

    if(me != null && world != null) {
        OrthographicCamera camera = GdxGame.getCameraInstance();
        camera.zoom = -(me.getWidth()/me.getOriginalWidth());
        camera.position.x = this.clamp(me.getX()/(-camera.zoom) - (GdxGame.WIDTH/2), 0, world.getWIDTH() - GdxGame.WIDTH) + GdxGame.WIDTH/2;
        camera.position.y = this.clamp(me.getY()/(-camera.zoom) - (GdxGame.HEIGHT/2), 0, world.getHEIGHT() - GdxGame.HEIGHT) + GdxGame.HEIGHT/2;
    }
}

@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {

    if(world != null) {
        background.render(sb, world);
        world.render(sb);
        foreground.render(sb, world);
    }


    if(message != null && message != "") {
        sb.begin();
        font.draw(sb, message, GdxGame.WIDTH/2 - message.length()*3, GdxGame.HEIGHT/2);
        sb.end();
    }

}

@Override
public void messageReceived(String message) {
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(message);
        if(MessageType.parse(json) == MessageType.ME) {
            me = Player.fromJSON(json.getJSONObject("data"));
        } else if(MessageType.parse(json) == MessageType.RENDER) {
            world = World.fromJSON(json.getJSONObject("data"));
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {}
}

@Override
public void connectionFailed(Throwable e) {
    message = "No internet connection or server is down.: " + e.getMessage();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    client.dispose();
}

private float clamp (float value, float min, float max){
    if(value < min/(-GdxGame.getCameraInstance().zoom)) return min/(-GdxGame.getCameraInstance().zoom);
    else if(value > max/(-GdxGame.getCameraInstance().zoom)) return max/(-GdxGame.getCameraInstance().zoom);
    return value;
}

}
```

Background and Foreground are drawn without problems, the only thing that is rendered uncorrectly is Player class and Food class mentioned above. They are being rendered inside a World render method. World class looks like this:

```
public class World {

private Array<Player> players;
private Array<Food> food;

private int WIDTH;
private int HEIGHT;

public Array<Player> getPlayers() {
    return players;
}

public void setPlayers(Array<Player> players) {
    this.players = players;
}

public Array<Food> getFood() {
    return food;
}

public void setFood(Array<Food> food) {
    this.food = food;
}

public Player getPlayerById(String id) {
    for(Player p : players) {
        if(p.getId().equals( id ))
            return p;
    }
    return null;
}

public static World fromJSON(JSONObject json) {
    World world = new World();

    Array<Player> players = new Array<Player>();
    Array<Food> food = new Array<Food>();

    try {

        world.setWIDTH(json.getInt("WIDTH"));
        world.setHEIGHT(json.getInt("HEIGHT"));

        JSONArray jsplayers = json.getJSONArray("players");
        for(int i = 0; i < jsplayers.length(); i++) {
            players.add(Player.fromJSON(jsplayers.getJSONObject(i)));
        }

        JSONArray jsfood = json.getJSONArray("food");
        for(int i = 0; i < jsfood.length(); i++) {
            food.add(Food.fromJSON(jsfood.getJSONObject(i)));
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {}

    world.setPlayers(players);
    world.setFood(food);

    return world;
}

public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
    if(players != null)
        for(Player player : players)
            if(player != null)
                player.render(sb);

    if(food != null)
        for(Food f : food)
            if(f != null)
            f.render(sb);
}

public int getWIDTH() {
    return WIDTH;
}

public void setWIDTH(int WIDTH) {
    this.WIDTH = WIDTH;
}

public int getHEIGHT() {
    return HEIGHT;
}

public void setHEIGHT(int HEIGHT) {
    this.HEIGHT = HEIGHT;
}
}
```

Comment: Well, I have a couple of questions: 1) how do you render your actors on the screen? 'Cos it strange for me to see  `sb.begin();  sb.end();` outside of screen class. 2) how do you create your Actors? 'Cos I see static initialization method as well as constructor, confusing. 3) Do you call  `Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);  Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` in the `render` method of your screen class?

Comment: 1) I am having a GameStateManager which renders current State (abstract class). I have PlayingState which extends from State and is calling render method of the all actors. 2) I instantiate them with fromJSON() static method from data sent over the tcp connection. 3) Yes of course I call glClear method in the render method of my ApplicationAdapter extending class... i will provide more code in the edit, but I think this is not the problem.

Comment: maybe the problem is that I instantiate the players and food 30 times per second everytime new and by the way I don't dispose the previous textures. Maybe I should do the algorithm that just override existing Players and Food with new properties values. hmm..?

Comment: nope I tried to reuse the existing classes instead of instantiating always the new classes and it doesn't fix the bug with black rectangles

Comment: well, I would first of all test `Food` and `Player` classes separately just to check that the problem is not there. I would create a couple of instances in `PlayingState` class and try to render them. The other thing that I noticed is that in your `Food` class there is no Exception handling in `fromJSON`  method. So, is it possible, that your `Food` instance is not properly created but you don't know about that?)

Comment: `Food` is being rendered on the right places, so I suppose it is correctly parsed from JSON, the only problem is that `Texture` in `Player` and `Food` classes is rendered as black rectangle. By the way the Background and Foreground textures are rendered well ....